# Solr search apostrophe issue

Tags: solr, apostrophe

Do Solr supports apostrophe in search field ? if Yes, what tokenizer/analyzer we need to apply ?

I'm currently using

```
<tokenizer class="solr.ClassicTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.ApostropheFilterFactory"/>
```

in my schema.xml.

Thank you.
Devendra

Comment: Check this
http://stackoverflow.com/a/11183076/2910342
explained in more detailed an accurate.

Answer (score 2):

`solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory` creates tokens of characters separated by splitting on whitespace.

[`solr.StandardTokenizerFactory`](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.StandardTokenizerFactory) leaves in-word apostrophes as well.

Comment: use rawQuery instead of q param in requestHandler, All symbols and strings will be treated equally.

Comment: there is no such a param, what do you mean?