# SOLR: Search not working with copy field and the custom field type

Tags: solr

In solrconfig.xml file

**Copy FIelds**

```
<copyField source="Name" dest="NameKeywords"/>
<copyField source="Keywords" dest="NameKeywords"/>
```

**New Field**

```
  <field name="NameKeywords" type="NameKeywordFieldType" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

**Custom Field Type**

```
<fieldType name="NameKeywordFieldType" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
       <filter class="solr.HyphenatedWordsFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
       <filter class="solr.HyphenatedWordsFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

So, when I searched anything with the **NameKeywords** field, nothing is working (empty array returned)

> Result of search with NameKeywords

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":1,
    "params":{
      "q":"NameKeywords:black",
      "_":"1582270957982"}},
  "response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"docs":[]
  }}
```

But when I searched with the **Name** field, All working fine.

> Result of search with Name

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0,
    "params":{
      "q":"Name:black",
      "fl":"Name",
      "rows":"2",
      "_":"1582270957982"}},
  "response":{"numFound":32560,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "Name":"40037 Black And Stripe Top, Black & Stripe / 10"},
      {
        "Name":"40037 Black And Stripe Top, Black & Stripe / 12"}]
  }}
```

So what is missing with the NameKeywords field?

Comment: I changed "KeywordTokenizerFactory" to "StandardTokenizerFactory" and its working..

Comment: Why are you using the `KeywordTokenizer` if you want to split the text on whitespace? Use the `StandardTokenizer` or the `WhitespaceTokenizer` in that case.

Comment: Can you please advise which is best for search as well as filters?

Comment: I got answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183017/difference-between-whitespacetokenizerfactory-and-standardtokenizerfactory

Comment: There is no one thing that is "best for search as well as filters". You have to define the set of behaviors that match what you want - each use case will be different. In general, using the same field for filtering/faceting/searching will usually not give a good experience for either. Use different fields for different use cases and behaviors.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using the `KeywordTokenizerFactory`, the token will not be created and the text will be treated as single token. When you search, you will have to search with that single token.

```
<analyzer>
  <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
</analyzer>
```

**In:** `"Please, email john.doe@foo.com by 03-09, re: m37-xq."`

**Out:** `"Please, email john.doe@foo.com by 03-09, re: m37-xq."`

If you want to generate the tokens, you should be using the `StandardTokenizer` or `WhitespaceTokenizer` as the tokeniser and not the KewordTokenizer.

The `StandardTokenizer` creates the words/tokens at punctuation characters, removing punctuation.

```
<analyzer>
  <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
</analyzer>
```

**In:** `"Please, email john.doe@foo.com by 03-09, re: m37-xq."`

**Out:** `"Please", "email", "john.doe", "foo.com", "by", "03", "09", "re", "m37", "xq"`

A `WhitespaceTokenizer` is a tokenizer that divides text at whitespace.

```
<analyzer>
  <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" rule="java" />
</analyzer>
```

**In:** `"To be, or what?"`

**Out:** `"To", "be,", "or", "what?"`

Answer (score 0):

Changed:

**KeywordMarkerFilterFactory To StandardTokenizerFactory**

```
<fieldType name="NameKeywordFieldType" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
       <filter class="solr.HyphenatedWordsFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
       <filter class="solr.HyphenatedWordsFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```